# sql query needs a specific order by

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by

My query without any order will result in:

```
owner   parent   target   key   value   operator   childOP
-----   ------   ------   ---   -----   --------   -------
267582  6        19       0     0       4          -1
267582  6        19       0     267582  32          4
267582  6        19       0     267583  32          4
267582  6        19       17    9       2           4
267582  6        19       20    8       2           4
267582  6        19       54    0       2           4
267582  6        19       60    5       0           4
267582  6        19       389   32      22         -1
```

But I need to get this ordered so I get a result as follows:

```
owner   parent   target   key   value   operator   childOP
-----   ------   ------   ---   -----   --------   -------
267582  6        19       0     267583  32          4
267582  6        19       0     267582  32          4
267582  6        19       0     0       4          -1
267582  6        19       389   32      22         -1
267582  6        19       60    5       0           4
267582  6        19       54    0       2           4
267582  6        19       20    8       2           4
267582  6        19       17    9       2           4
```

I already tried this query: .... WHERE owner = 267582 order by key asc, value desc

```
owner   parent   target   key   value   operator   childOP
-----   ------   ------   ---   -----   --------   -------
267582  6        19       0     267583  32          4
267582  6        19       0     267582  32          4
267582  6        19       0     0       4          -1
267582  6        19       17    9       2           4
267582  6        19       20    8       2           4
267582  6        19       54    0       2           4
267582  6        19       60    5       0           4
267582  6        19       389   32      22         -1
```

The result looked quite promising but is still not what I want.

But after keys = 0 the order was changed to DESC.

Is that even possible to achieve this way?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all sort key = 0 values first. Then sort key values desc. etc

```
order by case when key = 0 then 0 else 1 end, key desc, value desc
```

Comment: Hey jarlh,

this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot! =)